# Parameter value depending on another parameter in reports

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

i have a dropdown as parameter in my report which contain 3 values: value1 value2 and none. on clicking on value1 i want another parameter to appear as below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nRTl.png)

If i click on none then nothing should display.  Is it possible to achieve this by using filter/dataset? i am not sure how to do it. Any help will be really appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the names or captions of the parameter drop down control at run time. So you cannot have the second parameter labelled as 'Value 1' if 'Value 1 was selected in your first parameter.

You can however, control what is shown in your second parameter and have the list of items be dependent on your first parameter value.

For example, lets say we had a table called `products` that contained the following..

| ProdID | Category | Colour | Location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Bike | Red | A |
| 2 | Bike | Blue | A |
| 3 | Bike | Green | A |
| 4 | Car | Red | A |
| 5 | Car | Red | B |
| 6 | Car | Blue | B |
| 7 | Boat | Red | A |
| 8 | Boat | White | A |
| 9 | Boat | Blue | A |

If your first parameter was called `p1` had the following value, caption pairs

```
1 = Category
2 = Colour
3 = Location
```

Then the dataset query for the seconds parameter would be something like

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    CASE @p1
        WHEN 1 THEN [Category]
        WHEN 2 THEN [Colour]
        WHEN 3 THEN [Location]
    END as pValues
    FROM [products]
    ORDER BY 1;
```

If this does not help, please edit your question and explain exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: If this answered your question, please mark it as accepted (the check mark under to vote up/down buttons)